# Intellij IDEA Add Run buttons block to Tab bar or Status bar

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, customization

I'm looking for a way to hide the Navigation bar in Intellij IDEA without scarifying the Run buttons block. I can use the keyboard shortcut (which I use often, too) but it's nice to have an indicator if Instant Run is available and a button that ready to click.

Bellow you will find an image of the desired behavior.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize it like that at the moment. Feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.